# Which MS SQL-Server JDBC driver should I use?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

Is there a current opinion which MS SQL-Server JDBC driver I should use:

The official MS one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724

or JTDS: http://jtds.sourceforge.net/

And why?

Comment: Atlassian (makers of Confluence, JIRA, etc) recommend JTDS over the Microsoft JDBC, but it's possible the recommendation is outdated.  JTDS is based on the FreeTDS...

Comment: Exactly, Microsoft has a JDBC 4.0 compliant driver and JTDS still claims that MS only has a JDBC 2.0 driver. In tha past I have used JTDS but I'm not sure if it still the best option.

Comment: Yeah, JTDS is still at v1.2.5 for roughly a year since I paid it attention.

Answer (score 0):

The JTDS project look like is halted, the last release was 2 years ago, and it don't support many features that the official one has.

When a new release of SQL Server brings some new feature, like AlwaysON or Always Encrypted, Microsoft tries to release a JDBC driver with support for those features.

Check out the recently released JDBC 4.2 with support for JDK 8 and better support for XA transactions, it's almost on pair with the ADO.NET driver.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2015/09/02/download-the-new-jdbc-4-2-for-sql-server-driver.aspx